# Граббер для сайта

Tags: веб-программирование, поиск-программ

Подскажите, пожалуйста, лучший граббер для скачивания файлов (страницы, картинки, стили) с сайта.

Comment: В браузере "Сохранить страницу". А так популярный Teleport.

Comment: Для понятия "лучший" нужны объективные критерии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Teleport Pro](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleport_Pro)

Answer (score 3):

wget

Comment: Вроде бы это не граббер.